# Change/Override String.valueOf Java Android

Tags: java, android, string

How can I change the implementation of `String.valueOf(float sth)` for my whole activity?

I want to make it drop the `.0` for floats when converting them to `String` and only show `.` when there's something other than 0 after floating point.

I know I can make my own function like this: `FloatToString(float a)` but I'd like to avoid that and also learn overriding such functions if possible.

For example:

```
float a = 2.0;
Log.e("Sth",String.valueOf(a)); //result : 2
float b = 2.5;
Log.e("Sth",String.valueOf(a)); //result : 2.5
```

Comment: It's not possible I'm afraid. Static methods can't be overriden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible, `String` is a final class, you can not do , whatever you want to do , as it would be a security threat.

Moreover, if you are getting a need of changing the functionality of any `final` predefined class method, I am sorry to say but there are more chances of having some flaws in your code.

So instead of Overriding you can create an userdefined function `floatToString(float a)` and implement the logic in this function and call this function instead of `String.valueOf()` like :-

```
Log.e("Sth",floatToString((a));
```